# Пересчет мм в пиксели

Tags: canvas, html5

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - мне нужно задать размер элемента canvas 93мм x 53мм, но размер я могу задать только в пикселях. Получается это задача не имеет решения или как? Просто в 1мм может быть разное количество пикселей, в зависимости от разрешения монитора. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне поступить в данной ситуации?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
style="width:93mm; height:53mm"
```

Comment: ^___^ типа того.

Comment: Сейчас попробую, но не нашел такие единицы измерения... http://htmlbook.ru/content/edinitsy-izmereniya

Comment: Нашел, это абсолютные величины, огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

//Решение вполне рабочее на большинстве систем.

```
<body>
   <div id="ppitest" style="width:1in;visible:hidden;padding:0px"></div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
<script>screenPPI = document.getElementById('ppitest').offsetWidth;
scrinPPMM = screenPPI/25.4;//Стока пикселей в одном миллиметре на данном экране. Дальше справитесь?
</script>
```

Comment: Да, огромное спасибо, справлюсь!